# iOS and Android Max BLE advertise and scan bytes

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have been searching through stackoverflow; however, I seem to have found various conflicting answer's to questions regarding this. Given Android 5.1.1 and iOS 8.4.1 what is the maximum amount of bytes that can be sent through a connectionless BLE service to one another. It is my base understanding that it should be 20 bytes from BLE Specficiation(actually 23); however, I have seen queries where iOS was able to push 512 and android was able to increase it's MTU.

Also if it is possible to send more than 20 bytes in a connection would they all be recognized correctly at the scanners on iOS and android with a cross-platform application when it is receiving the packet's without direct connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Apple's [Best Practices for Setting Up Your Local Device as a Peripheral](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral/BestPracticesForSettingUpYourIOSDeviceAsAPeripheral.html):

> Although advertising packets in general can hold a variety of
>   information about the peripheral device, you may advertise only your
>   device’s local name and the UUIDs of any services you want to
>   advertise. That is, when you create your advertising dictionary, you
>   may specify only the following two keys:
>   CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey and
>   CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey. You receive an error if you
>   specify any other keys.
>
> There are also limits as to how much space you can use when
>   advertising data. When your app is in the foreground, it can use up to
>   28 bytes of space in the initial advertisement data for any
>   combination of the two supported advertising data keys. If this space
>   is used up, there are an additional 10 bytes of space in the scan
>   response that can be used only for the local name. Any service UUIDs
>   that do not fit in the allotted space are added to a special
>   “overflow” area; they can be discovered only by an iOS device that is
>   explicitly scanning for them. While your app is in the background, the
>   local name is not advertised and all service UUIDs are place in the
>   overflow area.
>
> **Note:** These sizes do not include the 2 bytes of header information
>   that are required for each new data type. The exact format of
>   advertising and response data is defined in the Bluetooth 4.0
>   specification, Volume 3, Part C, Section 11

If you use an unregistered 16 byte service UUID, I think that's going to give you about 12 bytes of data.

Available bytes in an advertising packet will differ from available bytes in a payload packet.